# How to display the calendar value selected in textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Calendar image and a text box. When i click on the image
I need to get the calendar and selected date should be displayed 
in the text box. I am using html and jQuery. How can I do this?

I know just using text box and calendar like this:

```
<input type="text" style="float: right;"id="datepicker">
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

But I need to do this like on click of:

```
<img src="images/calendar.gif" id='imgDatePicker'"/>
```

I should get the selected value and display in text box.

Sample image:

How can I do this?

Comment: are you using JQuery date picker? can you update fiddle? Can't understand your question

Comment: @ling.s yes i am using jquery, exactly what aksu mentioned, plz check my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true
}).next(".ui-datepicker-trigger").css("float", "left");
```

Another solution could be adding that `#datepicker` inside `div` tags, and then applying the styles to it.

PS: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works exactly what i wanted, just a small thing i need to move both textbox and image to right corner of the div, i used float: right, only textbox is moved to right, can i move bight also like buttonPosition : right;

Comment: Try now, i added little modification to my example.